# How to handle db failure at start and runtime

Tags: mongodb

**The premises:**

I'm using NodeJS, Mongodb Native 2.0+. I have created one connection (pool) which is keept open and reused in all modules. When production ready, the app and the db will be hosted on the same server, probably a VPS.

**Questions about MongoDB in a production ready environment.**

Should I anticipate that `Mongod` can crash? And if so, should I have some kind of autostart for it. Can "bugs" in my code be responsible for `Mongod` crashing?

If i should anticipate crasches, this probably also means that i should anticipate disruptions in my app when db cant be reached. What is the proper way to handle these? How long should i expect these disruptions to be?

If I start my app, manually close the `Mongod` and initiate a route call, the default response seems to be "waiting/loading" until `Mongod` is up again. I guess this default behaviour is ok if I dont expect disruption to be more than some seconds?

If `Mongod` is not up when starting the app, an exception will be thrown and the app will not start. This seems fine because without the db, the app cant do anything. Or should this be handled in another way?

I have made extensive search for this online, but have not found anything useful. Maybe I dont know what search terms to use...

There is alot of questions crammed up in one post here, but I hope someone could give me some answer or provide me with some links to good reading. The big question here is, **how do i handle db failure at start and runtime**

Comment: Scan through the [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) for useful sections. In particular, you will want to read about [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/).

Comment: I have not yet looked into replication. I thought this was something that I could care about later when I have a massive amount of data... I'm probably confusing it with sharding. Actually the first line of the replication chapter says: *Replica sets provide redundancy and high availability, and are the basis for all production deployments.* =)

Comment: Replicate from the start, shard when you must.

Comment: So, if I set up a standard replication set with three members for production. Does this mean i don't need additional code for handling db failure during runtime, because I can count on that at least one mongod is (practically) always up?

Comment: If the primary goes down, you do need to account for the election period, when there's no primary that can be written to. I think different drivers handle that differently, however, so you'd need to experiment with your driver.